# How to reduce a polynomial

Tags: ring-theory

I'm studing theory about polynomial ring, I have this exercise:

> For what prime number does the polynomial $f=x^3+\overline{2}x
>  +\overline{2}\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ admit $\overline{3}$ as a root (I hope the term is correct)?

I work in this way
$$f(\overline{3}) = \overline{27}+\overline{6}+\overline{2}=\overline{35}$$
But this is correct if $\overline{35}=\overline{0}$; this happens in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ if and only if:
$$35\equiv0\pmod p$$
So I can say $p=5$.
The exercise continues, but I don't know how to proceed:

> Write $f$ as product of irreducible factors in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: You could also have $p=7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

Since $\deg f = 3$, we know that either

- $f$ is irreducible
- $f = g_1 g_2$ for two factors with (w.l.o.g.) $\deg g_1 = 1$ and $\deg g_2 = 2$, where $g_2$ is irreducible.
- $f = g_1 g_2 g_3$ for three factors with $\deg g_i = 1$ for $i  = 1,2,3$.

Now, you may assume that the $g_i$ are monic (i.e., their leading coefficient is 1), so they correspond to roots of $f$. In other words, if you know the roots of $f$, you can easily find its irreducible factors.

Comment: And how can i work in a more general environment. Where $\deg f$ is not necessarely equal to 3?

Comment: In general, things become more complicated, since there are many possibilities for the degree distribution of the irreducible factors. Basically, there are (somewhat expensive) algorithms for factoring polynomials over a field with given characteristic; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomial_over_finite_field_and_irreducibility_tests for an overview, or any computer algebra textbook for details.

Comment: What about Ruffini?

Comment: Do you mean the Abel-Ruffini theorem? If working over $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$, it is not really relevant, since you can find the zeroes of a polynomial by brute-force search. Also, depending on $p$, it might take a different form (my Galois theory class was quite a while ago, so I'm not certain).

Comment: Yes, i know the theory. I would see some examples, cause this theorem is the only one that I can use.